# Deleting GDI objects does not decrease their number

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi

When I look in the Task Manager on the number of GDI objects for my process, then I see that not every call of function DeleteObject() for a GDI object causes decrementing this number, and the function call does not return FALSE (as it should if the object deletion was unsuccessful). I'm using plain Windows API GDI functions without additional libraries and wrappers such as MFC. Why such situation can happen and does it mean GDI resource leakage?

Here is the code how to recreate the problem:

```
void gditest()
{
    HBRUSH h = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 237, 5));
    HRGN rgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 100, 100, 0);

    FillRgn(g_DC, rgn, h);

    int before = GetGuiResources(GetCurrentProcess(), GR_GDIOBJECTS);
    int rs = DeleteObject( h );
    if ( !rs )
        throw;
    int after = GetGuiResources(GetCurrentProcess(), GR_GDIOBJECTS);
}
```

Variables 'before' and 'after' are equal. g_DC is the HDC of the main window.

Comment: Please supply an SSCCE

Comment: The standard mistake is still having the object selected in a device context.  And yes, that's a leak.

Comment: Shouldn't the DeleteObject() return zero in this case? MSDN for DeleteObject: "If the specified handle is not valid or is currently selected into a DC, the return value is zero. "

Comment: A DC is a GDI object as well, are you calling `ReleaseDC` as well as deleting the brush?

Comment: Is it necessary to release DC after each call of GDI function? I initialize a global DC handle to the main window on the program start and all the functions use only this DC. (The program is single-threaded.)

Comment: I think you need to post more code before anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: @Jonathan : Yes, I supposed the same, but the code that creating, using and deleting GDI objects is rather scattered and I thought that someone who knows internals of DeleteObject may know when a successful call of the function doesn't release GDI resources.

Comment: I updated the post with the code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: You're leaking the region handle.

Answer (score 1):

Stock GDI objects are never created nor destroyed. They are maintained by Windows and you can use them as you wish. If you have code like the following

```
HPEN hPen = (HPEN)GetStockObject(BLACK_PEN);
DeleteObject(hPen);
```

you will not see the GDI count go up or down. The call to `DeleteObject` will return `TRUE` even though the object is not really deleted.

If you want to check for resource leaks you can place calls to [`GetGuiResources`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683192.aspx) in your code to compare the before/after values. You would typically place those calls where the resource counts should match, i.e. creation and destruction of resources match.

Comment: I don't think you're ever supposed to call `DeleteObject` on a stock object.

Comment: @Ben It is not necessary, but it is [not harmful either](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144925.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable: In the debugger the DeleteObject() is stepped over, returns non-zero, but the number of GDI objects in the TaskMan remains the same. =(And the second call of DeleteObject to the same object fails.

Comment: Addition: GetGuiResources returns the same number as TaskMan and the returned number before and after DeleteObject() doesn't change as well. =(

Answer (score 0):

You should select a NULL object to Device Context before deleting the object.

Example:

SelectObject(g_DC, GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH));
DeleteObject(h);